# Selenium with Python - find elements of more than one css class

Tags: python, selenium

I need to lookup a list of items that have various css classes, but have them returned in a single list, so I can loop through it, in below case I need to pick up all 4 items.

```
<li class="dropdown">
<li class="dropdown">
<li class="dropdown">
<li class="dropdown right">
```

I'm trying the below patterns, but it does not work.

```
menuItems = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//li[@class="dropdown"|@class="dropdown right"]')

menuItems2 = browser.find_element_by_class_name('dropdown' | 'dropdown right')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `find_elements_by_class_name` or `find_elements_by_css_selector` method. It returns an array, then you can navigate through these elements like this :

```python
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".dropdown")
# or
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("dropdown")
# elements[0]
# elements[1]
# ...
```

If you want elements that have `.dropdown` and `.right` CSS class, then  :

```python
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".dropdown.right")
# elements[0]
# elements[1]
# ...
```

Comment: I tried this, but I still get: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: Your example just gives results for dropdown, I need a list of both "dropdown" and "dropdown right"

Comment: @Turo: Nope, his code gives all classes that `dropdown` in the class name. So `<li class="dropdown right">` or `<li class="dropdown">` or `<li class="dropdown left">` etc.

Comment: then 2 separated list? because, they have all `.dropdown` class. I had an example

Comment: Thank you Louis. I had something different in mind, but I'll post another question. Your answer is the right one for the question asked.